# Android adb show "Allow USB debugging?" window

Tags: android, adb

I am using Mobogenie software to backup data on my smartphone. When I do it, program invokes "Allow USB debugging?" window on my device, obviously via ADB. The question is - how? In the screenshot below (it is in Russian language)

[image]

button which is in red ellipse says: "Show this popup window again" and when I press it, my device shows "Allow USB debugging?" window. But i couldn't find any useful information about how to do the same thing - with ADB (which command should I use) or any other way. Maybe sombody got an idea? Or is there any way to kind of trace commands or find out how this progrom does it?

Comment: do `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: Check this link, its a feature of 4.2.2 http://adbdriver.com/documentations/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android-devices.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADB Secure device authorizations are stored in a whitelist located here: `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

There's no way to remove RSA keys from the whitelist without having root access.

Having said that... If you do not "Allow USB Debugging" when that window pops up (by pressing cancel) **or** if you do not check the box that says "Always allow from this computer", then the RSA key is not stored in the whitelist.  By running `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`, it forces a new check of the connected computer's RSA key.

My guess is that the button that is circled is there basically just kills and restarts the ADB server to have the popup come back, in case the user did not "Always allow" or if they Cancelled the request.

EDIT:  I see that Mobogenie also includes a "one click root" feature... As sketchy as that sounds, if your device is rooted, then Mobogenie *could* be deleting your computer's stored key from your whitelist.  As for this theory, there are multiple methods - one being simply doing a pure delete:

```
adb start-server
adb shell
cd /data/misc/adb
rm abd_keys
exit
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same issue in my lenovo mobile. Initially I thought the issue is with my mobile.

But actually the issue is the `adb` don't have enough permission to read the `rsa key` to communicate with the device. When we run `adb server` it'll create a folder named `.android`(Linux - `/home/--username--/.android`, Windows - `C:/Users/--username--/.android`) in the home directory of the current user which contains the `adb rsa key` files used to communicate between the devices.

When I check the folder is assigned with `root` permission(I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't know how its assigned). So when I try to run `adb start-server` it is trying to create `.android` folder. But the current folder with root access is not allowing this to create the adb keys. That's why its failed.

So I deleted the folder using below command. Use the particular method to delete the folder based on your operating system. Below I mentioned for linux.

> sudo rm -rf .android

Then restarted the `adb server` using below command.

> adb start-server

Now It created the `.android` folder with the current user permission. Once done this I got the `Allow USB debugging` dialog.

Hope it help someone.